# Type MisMatch Require Tuple2, but Map Found

Tags: scala, apache-spark

it seems that we can't use Map as the return type, the below code will show error, ***Tuple2 require, but Map Found.***, Any tips is appreciated. Thanks~

```
def GetCategories(df: DataFrame, col: String)= mutable.Map[String, Int] {
  val distinctValues = df.select(col).distinct().collect()
  var dict: Map[String, Int] = mutable.Map[String, Int]()

  for (a <- 0 until distinctValues.size) {
    dict.put(distinctValues(a).toString(), a)
  }

  dict.foreach(println)
  dict
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to return a `Map[String, Int]`:

```
def getCategories(df: DataFrame, col: String): mutable.Map[String, Int] = {}
```

Note that the `mutable.Map[String, Int]` comes after a colon and before the equals sign.

Comment: thank you sir, just using scala this days, make this mistake mainly for Intellij IDE, which appear '=' automatically,